# Declaring constants or using numbers inside the code

Tags: c++, constants

So, i have this C++ test and the teacher is really hard on declaring constants instead of using numbers directly in the code. In the example below i have even declared ZERO as a constant.

Is this unnecessary or is this a good thing to do? Does this way take up more memory or make the code "slower"?

```
int main() {

    int kmStart, kmEnd;
    const int ZERO = 0;

    cout << "Starting Kms? ";
    cin >> kmStart;

    cout << "Ending Kms? ";
    cin >> kmEnd;

    while (kmStart < ZERO || kmStart > kmEnd) {
        cout << "Invalid Input!" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Starting Kms? ";
        cin >> kmStart;

        cout << "Ending Kms? ";
        cin >> kmEnd;
    }

}
```

Comment: The constant will be resolved and optimized at compile time. It won't use extra memory or hurt performance at runtime.

Comment: Of course this is unnecessary! That isn't what constants are for! In fact, as seen in Bathshebas answer, this could actually hurt in a larger program!

Comment: Having a constant `ZERO` is like having a constant `FORTY_FIVE`. It is no different from entering the literal value `45`. Use constants to represent non specific values that describe their purpose.

Comment: Naming values that otherwise would appear to be arbitrary, is good. The unnamed arbitrary values are called **magic constants**. Everybody agree that they're bad and that naming them is good. But naming zero is bad. Using all uppercase naming for a non-macro, and more generally using other language's conventions in C++, is bad.

Comment: Adding a `ZERO` constant is just bonkers. Adding a `PI` constant rather than writing `3.14159` everywhere is not (although pi doesn't change at least you'll be using the same aproximate value everywhere). Adding a `WORKING_HOURS_PER_WEEK` constant makes a lot of sense since if (when) it changes you just have to update the constant in *one* place. Performance wise it makes no difference either way.

Comment: @Galik I would argue that zero is a special case: it does not change when you decide to rescale all your definitions by a (later) more convenient factor. FORTY_FIVE does. Zero is dimensionless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of properly named constants is mandatory for a development of long-living applications. Managing plain numeric literals quickly goes off hands. Consider the following example:

```
foo(42);
bar(42);
```

It has several problems:

- it is not possible to guess where 42 value came from
- it is not possible to guess whether `42` in both function calls is just a coincidence or we are intentionally passing the same value
- as a consequence of the previous point changing program behavior may be challenging because we need to manually identify all the places where particular value that we want to adjust is utilized

If your application consists of hundreds of files it will be a literal nightmare.

So if constants are used instead the example code piece may become

```
constexpr int const fast_foobing_rate{42};
constexpr int const slow_barring_coeff{42};

foo(fast_foobing_rate);
bar(slow_barring_coeff);
```

or

```
constexpr int const days_in_week_count{7};
constexpr int const frobbing_weeks_count{6};
inline constexpr int get_frob_repetitions_count(void) noexcept
{
    return(days_in_week_count * frobbing_weeks_count);
}

foo(get_frob_repetitions_count());
bar(get_frob_repetitions_count());
```

So now:

- we are able to track origins of values
- we can locate places where these persistent values are used
- we can easily adjust these persistent values by modifying their definitions and our changes will be automatically applied across the entire codebase

And with all these benefits we won't suffer from performance penalties. Depending on constant type there could even be some benefits for performance as well.

Answer (score 6):

`constexpr int ZERO = 0;` would almost certainly be completely compiled out.

Note the new keyword `constexpr`, from C++11 onwards.

For you current code, `ZERO` may well be compiled out, but even if it isn't any degradation in performance will be negligible cf. the input / output functions.

I wonder why your teacher regards `ZERO` to be clearer than `0`. Everyone knows what they are dealing with when they see a `0`. For example, `ZERO` could feasibly mean `'0'`, or even `"0"` which are entirely different beasts: you'd always have be checking back through the code when debugging this.

Comment: What would you do when dealing with other numbers like 10, if one were to divide or add 10 in an equation for example.

Comment: Well I'd just use 10. At least I can see right away that it's a literal of type `int`.

Comment: @FredrikBurmester: It **depends**. For example, in converting decimal to binary the 10 is obvious. But when the 10 is a guesstimate of some value, name it. And in general, remember that the purpose of the code is mainly to communicate to humans. Just ask yourself what the 10 communicates to you, in any given concrete case. If it's unclear, name it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, using constants instead of numbers in the code directly can make your code more readable and easier to maintain.

Consider the following example:

For example you have some kind of simulation with a timestep of 0.1 seconds and you need this timestep value in different locations of your source code, then it would be easier to use a

```
const double timesstep = 0.1
```

instead of writing 0.1 every where.

Advantage is:

- only one line must be changed if you want to change the value of
  timestep
- the code becomes more readable, if you know the constants meaning

But in your case, I think its more readable to use 0 instead of zero, or you rename it to something more expressive as "minimum_start" or something like that...

Comment: I know this is not relevant but note that successive increments of 0.1 equals floating point merry hell. Better to use something like `t = T * step / steps`.

Comment: It is just an example why you should use constans instead of magic numbers. In a real world example it depends on the problem how to define something like a timestep, timepoint, timedelta or whatever ...

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, for integer constant I am using enumerations (source == Scott Meyer, Effective C++) :

```
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  enum Constant {
    NTRY = 32,
    NEQ = 8,
    SMAX = 200000000,
    ALERT = 65536
  };

  size_t ntry (Constant::NTRY);
  std::cout << "ntry == " << ntry << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```